# Why do functions inside ready(), not execute systematically when I refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I've got a function inside ready(), and when I press Enter in the address bar, this function works.

However, when I press Refresh more than once, the function is not triggered.

Then I tried to refresh the page 20 times in a row and the function actually worked only once out of 4 times.
Why is it not systematic?

Note: my function shifts images using CSS

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

```
<html>
<body>


  <div id='container' style='width: 60px; height: 95px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <img class='pic' id='default_pic' src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>
</div>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       function shiftPic(photo)    {    
           var photo_width = $(photo).width();
           var container_width = $('#container').width();

           photo_shift= (container_width - photo_width)/2;
           console.log(photo_shift);
           $(photo).css('margin-left',photo_shift);
}

 shiftPic('#default_pic');

  });
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create http://jsfiddle.net demo or link to the page in question. Also post your code. My [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mCjLE/) does not show this behaviour, so you have to provide some evidence.

Comment: +1 @FelixKling - indeed - demo please, keen to see this behavior! cheerios!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using `load` on these images would you?  Could be related to the images being cached vs not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. I am creating a jsfiddle. @JamesMontagne: I am not using load() on this specific page. Actually it's the same images, I just shift them to center them in the container

Comment: The example is at http://jsfiddle.net/gn6by/   For some reason, the Google pic is not centered and it should be. But in my script, this script works when I press Enter but it works/fails randomly when I keep refreshing. Also, when it works, the shift is not instantaneous. It takes a split second to be executed.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I used load() for these photos, but only in the Upload handler (so, in a separate file)

Comment: i changed the library to jQuery 1.7 and it works on each page load: http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/gn6by/1/. ??? Post all of your code, esp img load code.

Comment: Hi, have you tried locally with a local image? It seems that refreshing many times in a row confuses Javascript, which is really weird. The image is loaded with html (not dynamically).

Comment: I put the html file in edit, you just have to change the img src to something local.

Comment: The jfiddle that ampersand posted works just fine

Comment: Your fiddle did not work because you included Mootools, not jQuery. If you had a look at the console, you would have seen the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the problem that you're applying that logic before the image has loaded in some cases? Keep in mind that the document ready event potentially fires before the image has finished loading (and therefore doesn't yet have a size), which could lead to the inconsistent behavior you're encountering.

As your code is written, it's basically equivalent to not wrapping it in any event handler at all since it's already at the bottom of the page (a good thing):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='container' style='width: 60px; height: 95px; overflow: hidden;'>
      <img class='pic' id='default_pic' src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'>

    <script>
      function shiftPic(photo)    {    
        var photo_width = $(photo).width();
        var container_width = $('#container').width();

        photo_shift= (container_width - photo_width)/2;
        console.log(photo_shift);
        $(photo).css('margin-left',photo_shift);
      }

      shiftPic('#default_pic');
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to wait until after images have finished loading to run your code, you can use the window's load event instead:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='container' style='width: 60px; height: 95px; overflow: hidden;'>
      <img class='pic' id='default_pic' src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'>

    <script>

      $(window).load(function() {   
        var photo_width = $(photo).width();
        var container_width = $('#container').width();

        photo_shift= (container_width - photo_width)/2;
        console.log(photo_shift);
        $(photo).css('margin-left',photo_shift);
      });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Or, you can only wait until the specific image has finished loading (a good idea on real pages with things like social sharing widgets, analytics scripts, Flash movies, unrelated additional images, etc which can push the window load event out quite a bit):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='container' style='width: 60px; height: 95px; overflow: hidden;'>
      <img class='pic' id='default_pic' src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'>

    <script>

      $('#default_pic').load(function() {   
        var photo_width = $(photo).width();
        var container_width = $('#container').width();

        photo_shift= (container_width - photo_width)/2;
        console.log(photo_shift);
        $(photo).css('margin-left',photo_shift);
      });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```